# problem running gufw in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10

```
android@android:~$ gufw
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_modifier_mask: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_replace_virtual_modifiers: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_modifier_mask: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_replace_virtual_modifiers: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_modifier_mask: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_replace_virtual_modifiers: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_modifier_mask: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_replace_virtual_modifiers: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_modifier_mask: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_replace_virtual_modifiers: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_modifier_mask: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_replace_virtual_modifiers: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_modifier_mask: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_replace_virtual_modifiers: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_modifier_mask: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_replace_virtual_modifiers: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_modifier_mask: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_replace_virtual_modifiers: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_modifier_mask: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:21126): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_replace_virtual_modifiers: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed
/usr/bin/gufw-pkexec: line 13: 21126 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) python3 ${LOCATIONS[${i}]} $1
```

Comment: Let's try `sudo apt-get install python-gobject && sudo apt-get install --reinstall gufw`

Comment: check this
https://askubuntu.com/questions/980357/how-to-run-xorg-programs-on-wayland

Answer (score 9):

I'm a Gufw developer.

You can not run any root UI (Gparted, Synaptic, Gufw...) because of Wayland.

Related bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gui-ufw/+bug/1713238

All info here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/backintime/+bug/1713313/comments/44

As you can read in that link, I'm afraid that it will be not fixed, because it was closed as *won't fix* :/

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1274451

A hug and I'm so sorry.

Comment: Well, the Ubuntu bug is not closed, is it?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson is not related to Ubuntu, it's related to Wayland. Any root UI in a distro with Wayland will not work :(

Comment: Right, but I have the impression that they plan to implement some kind of fix/workaround. Maybe I'm wrong. Also, please see the answer I just posted.

Comment: why doesn't wayland allow those apps to work? seems like a serious downside to using wayland

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I think what needs to happen is that apps like Gufw need to use PolicyKit?

Answer (score 6):

A dirty workaround, but this is one way to make gufw work on Ubuntu 17.10 with Wayland:

- Create the file `~/bin/gufw` and give it this contents:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  xhost SI:localuser:root
  /usr/bin/gufw
  xhost -SI:localuser:root
  ```
- Make the file executable:

  ```
  chmod +x ~/bin/gufw
  ```

***Edit:***

A more step by step explanation would be:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal window.
- Run the command:

  ```
  mkdir -p bin
  ```

  (i.e. type it and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
- Open the *gedit* text editor with this command:

  ```
  gedit bin/gufw
  ```
- Copy the contents as above and paste it into the *gedit* window.
- Save and quit *gedit*.
- Run the command:

  ```
  chmod +x bin/gufw
  ```
- Quit the terminal window by running the command:

  ```
  exit
  ```

Comment: Thanks! Entering `xhost +SI:localuser:root` in the command line was enough to run it, but I'm not sure it's gonna survive restarting my computer.

Comment: @Johannes: It won't, but the above suggested solution survives a reboot.

Answer (score 3):

**Re-installation not really required**;

After a quick search, I found that Gufw is missing a python dependency. It appears that the python-gi package needs to be added as a dependency.

***Steps to fix***:

1. sudo apt install python-gi
2. gufw
3. Type in password

Comment: i have problem for ubuntu 17.10 now

Comment: Does not fix it for me (running `Mint 18.2 Sonya` based on `16.04.1-Ubuntu`)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Accidentally found the solution for gparted over SSH [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477732/run-gparted-over-ssh).

```
sudo -E gufw
```

This should work - assuming `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is properly configured.

Answer (score 0):

```
xhost si:localuser:root

pip3 install ufw
sudo apt-get install python-gobject
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gufw
sudo gufw
```

worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04! I had the same issue!
I hope I'm not forgetting any cmd as I tried a lot of things...