# GParted doesn't Start?

Tags: gparted

I have installed GParted in 17.10, GParted doesn't Start when I click on icon of GParted, and I tried to start it from terminal using *sudo gparted* it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 2):

The duplicate question explains it. I wrote an [answer with Gufw in mind](https://askubuntu.com/a/968800), and if you replace all occurrences of `gufw` there with `gparted-pkexec`, that solution works for GParted too.